# error in kernel source code of linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, extern

I modified the kernel source code `r8169.c` and calculating the `timestamp` as below:

```
s64 a;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(a);
a = time();
```

*I did not add the original timestamp function call*

I am using the variable a in another source file in kernel: `ip_input.c`

```
extern s64 a;

s64 b,c;
b= time();
c = b-a;
```

I receive this error:

```
 ERROR: undefined reference to a
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Do you link `ip_input` though?

Comment: using which command you are inserting the modules ??

Comment: procfs is used to read from kernel to user space. I specified in procfs as extern s64 a,b,c;

Comment: r u running both .c file i.e `r8169.c` and `ip_input.c` and while loading modules r u using makefile??

Comment: ofcourse yes!!! I am giving make command to built the entire process completely.

Comment: if in makefile you are loading both the modules then it should not create problem.

Comment: can you update makefile ??

Comment: updated it!! later showing the above error

Comment: This is not the complete source code. Where and how do you define `s64 a`?

Comment: I am giving make for updating the kernel code

Comment: I was asking about Makefile's content can u show that ??

Answer (score 1):

From the incomplete source code, I guess that

```
s64 a;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(a);
a = time();
```

is inside a function and therefore, `a` cannot be exported, because it is local to that function.

To use `a` outside of this module, you must define it with file scope, e.g.

```
s64 a;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(a);

void some_function()
{
    a = time();
}
```

This allows the symbol for `a` to be exported and then used in another module.

Answer (score 1):

r8169.c is a module, whereas ip_input.c is in the main kernel.  The main kernel cannot import symbols from a module.  The fix for this is to declare your variable within ip_input.c, and import it from r8169.c.  You also have to use file scope as Olaf mentioned.

ip_input.c:

```
s64 a, b, c;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(a);

void someFunc() {
   b=time();
   c=b-a;
}
```

r8169.c:

```
extern s64 a;

void someFunc() {
    a=time();
}
```